# Unable to remove ActiveMQ ScheduledMessage?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I am trying to remove scheduled delayed message through [Thoughts of Tim Bish](http://timbish.blogspot.com/2010/10/enhanced-jms-scheduler-in-activemq.html)

**Message scheduled properly but unable to remove scheduled message.**

Am using ActiveMq-5.15.3

Also enabled  **schedulerSupport="true"** from activemq.xml

Here is my code

```
     /**
      * #1 Send 5 message with delayed time 60sec's        
      */
    //send delayed message
    Destination destination = session.createQueue("test");
    producer = session.createProducer(destination);
    Message message = session.createTextMessage(getCustomerMessage());
    long delay = 1 * 1000*60;
    message.setLongProperty(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY, delay);

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++{
        producer.send(message);
    }
    //end
```

After ran above code then web console show result like below screen shot.
 *Scheduled* tab: 
           [image]

After one minute all messages moved to queues (like normal messages) that's fine.

But, I want to cancel all scheduled message and No need to put queues.
I run below program for remove all scheduled messages. (before 1 minute)

```
    //remove all schedule
    Destination destination = session.createQueue("test");
    MessageProducer mproducer = session.createProducer(destination);
    Message request = session.createMessage();
    request.setStringProperty(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULER_ACTION,
            ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULER_ACTION_REMOVEALL);
    mproducer.send(request);
   //end
```

Above code Not removed from scheduled message. Just put into queues as normal message.

Tried also

> createTopic(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULER_MANAGEMENT_DESTINATION)
>   instead of createQueue("test")

remove through browse property also not work

```
    browser.receive(5000);
```

browser.receive always return null

Please correct me what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the scheduler enabled?  How do you know the job is not removed?  More information is required

Comment: @TimBish
Updated my question. Please look at again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to remove all scheduled messages from a real destination and not the management destination for the Scheduler.  You should be directing the remove-all to the management destination as below:

```
Destination management = session.createTopic(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULER_MANAGEMENT_DESTINATION);
MessageProducer mproducer = session.createProducer(destination);
Message request = session.createMessage();
request.setStringProperty(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULER_ACTION,
        ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULER_ACTION_REMOVEALL);
mproducer.send(request);
```

Comment: Thanks lot , both (remove all and specific message) are working fine.
Now I am understand properly.
Thanks again.

Comment: I'm running Artemis `2.6.4` and can't get this to work. Scheduling delayed messages works fine with both STOMP and AMQP but I just can't remove them. 

I've tried posting a message with above mentioned properties to `ActiveMQ.Scheduler.Management` but nothing ever gets routed to the reply-to queue (temporary or not).

Do I need to do some additional configuring to make this work? All I ever see in docs, blogs and forum is a variation of your example above. Btw, I'm using node so I've tried with `rhea` and `node-stomp` libraries, which should not matter.

Comment: I'd guess Artemis doesn't implement that feature and you'd have to request an enhancement to get it added.  I haven't tried it with Artemis.

Comment: I went through the code and the only reference to it is in a few broken, leftover ActiveMQ 5x tests. I really like the project but the documentation leaves a lot to be desired. Thanks @TimBish, I appreciate the answer and, in case anyone with the same problem reads this, I wrote a simple client/wrapper around the Jolokia REST API to remove the messages. Since I only need to remove individual messages from time to time, this will do for now.